# How can I apply box function to detect face in colab?

Tags: python, opencv, keras, google-colaboratory, face-detection

I trying to give the prediction output with box that detect human face using google colab but after I run the video not have the box so how can I applied it in the codes??

The code:

```
def prediction (filepath):
  input_shape = (128, 128, 3)
  pr_data = []
  detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filepath)
  frameRate = cap.get(5)
  while cap.isOpened():
      frameId = cap.get(1)
      ret, frame = cap.read()
      if ret != True:
          break
      if frameId % ((int(frameRate)+1)*1) == 0:
          face_rects, scores, idx = detector.run(frame, 0)
          for i, d in enumerate(face_rects):
              x1 = d.left()
              y1 = d.top()
              x2 = d.right()
              y2 = d.bottom()
              crop_img = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]
              data = img_to_array(cv2.resize(crop_img, (128, 128))).flatten() / 255.0
              data = data.reshape(-1, 128, 128, 3)
              print((model.predict(data) > 0.5).astype("int32"))
              outt=''
  if ((model.predict(data) > 0.5).astype("int32")[0][0] == 0 ):
    return 'Real'
  else:
    return'Fake'
```

Comment: Welcome! It looks like you're trying to draw a rectangle. Would you like to know how to do that? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=draw+rectangle+opencv+python